# why are there blank cells in this grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

In sections within the story, I'm using `display: grid` and `grid-auto-flow: dense;` but the `<div>`s within are not flowing properly:

http://www.chicagomag.com/Chicago-Magazine/January-2019/What-CTA-Workers-Know/index.php?previewmode=on&hide=on

I've tried everything - changing the column rules, `row-gap`, etc. Cannot figure out why there are extra gaps.

[image: click the section headers to open the sections.]

Here's the css:

```
.q-section {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin: 10px;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-gap: 25px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(252px, 1fr)); !important;
}


.q-section.active {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.q-section:not(:last-of-type) {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.q-section > div {
    font-family: "proxima-nova";
    padding: 15px;
    grid-row-end: auto;
    color: #555;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="q-section">

        <div><img src="icons.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>


        <div>What makes my day  is a person who says, “Have a great day,”  and then goes and  sits their ass down.</div>

        <div class="purple">I let them vent. I understand, I’ve ridden the bus. You’re out there freezing your tail off. “Man, where the hell have you been?” Usually a couple minutes later, they’ll come up and be like, “Hey, sorry about that.”</div>
        <div>In the morning I got over a thousand people on the train, and pretty much every one of them have headphones on. People don’t talk anymore.</div>
        <div>Some drivers just face straight forward. As long as they hear that Ventra card going off, they don’t care. But I can’t help myself. I have to talk to people. </div>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: invisible characters copied over from the source Word document were reserving their own spaces. solution: just select anything in between `<div>`s and delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Without more code to review its hard to say but it looks like you are pulling some bad data. Blocks are being created because it thinks something is there.

[Souce Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKrBd.png)

Comment: Well, post your code so that others can see what is going on.

Comment: SOLVED: invisible characters copied over from the source Word document were reserving their own spaces. solution: just select anything in between ````<div>````s and delete it.